# Overriding Bootstrap custom.css.scss in Rails not working as expected

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

**My Setup**

I edited `.col-lg-4` in Bootstrap for Rails and included them in my `custom.css.scss` file after the import statements to include zero padding.

**The Problem**

I need to override .embed-responsive video in bootstrap css to not have a width property and to set padding to zero. I managed to work out a temporary solution by manually importing a bootstrap file but I would like to still use the bootstrap sass gem and override those properties.

However they don't seem to be overriding them in the Custom.css.scss file.

**Mixed Behavior** (`Custom.css.scss`)

The problem is that if I import Bootstrap-sprockets & Bootstrap, it seems to ignore my css and I can't set what I need to set as mentioned above.

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

.thumb{
}

.col-lg-4 {
    padding: 50px !important;
}
.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item,.embed-responsive   embed,.embed-responsive iframe,.embed-responsive object,.embed-responsive video{position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;height:100%;border:0}
```

Application.css

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

I have also used rake `assets:clean`.

EDIT: After some attempts, the tests revealed that if I provide a custom bootstrap CSS file and not import bootstrap in Custom.css.scss will solve the problem.

However I would want to use the bootstrap sass gem if possible. Is there a fix to my current implementation?

---

Comment: Show me your `applicaton.scss`.

Comment: Added more details and showed my application.scs

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you could just override the variable `$grid-gutter-width` in variables?

---

Here's my usual setup. I don't use `require`, but include individual CSS manually to control hierarchy:

```
 * require_tree .
 * require_self
 */

@import "bootstrap_variables";
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

// Bootstrap components
@import "navbar";
@import "forms";

// App components
@import "orders";
```

1. To override Bootstrap variables (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss), I include it before anything else. Always check for variables overrides first before anything else.
2. To override some Bootstrap components, I include them next in separate CSS.
3. For app-specific styles, which I categorized it based on model/view, I create another CSS for it.

This is very basic, but it works very well for most occasions.